# woocommerce remove validation on product detail page

Tags: woocommerce, product, cart

I don't want woocommerce to check variations selected or not on product page. right now on product page I have two types of variations in two dropdown lists. when I click on the "add to cart" button, woocommerce checks whether both the variations are selected or not. if any of the two variations is not selected, it throws error. I don't want woocommerce to check this. I want to remove validations and want the item to add to cart when i click on the button. thanks

Comment: **This is not possible,** as a product variation is maid *(in your case)* of 2 different selected attribute values that need to be "selected", to allow a real defined product variation to be added to cart.

Comment: isn't there any way to use this woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation hook and return true in any case? I did this but it does not work